# How to add point that distribute evenly on XAxis in mschart?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, charts, axes

c# mschart vs2010 .net4

```
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(0, 1);
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(7, 1;
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(8,1);
```

i was hoping that the 3 points looks like this

```
 .      . .
```

but it turned out like this

```
 . . .
```

Why?
Thank you

code of chart

```
chartArea1.AxisX.InterlacedColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLight;
chartArea1.AxisX.Interval = 1D;
chartArea1.AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
chartArea1.AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1D;
chartArea1.AxisX.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
chartArea1.AxisX.IsInterlaced = true;
chartArea1.AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;
chartArea1.AxisX.MajorTickMark.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Maroon;
chartArea1.AxisX.ScrollBar.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisY.ArrowStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisArrowStyle.SharpTriangle;
chartArea1.AxisY.InterlacedColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
chartArea1.AxisY.Interval = 1D;
chartArea1.AxisY.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
chartArea1.AxisY.IsInterlaced = true;
chartArea1.AxisY.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
chartArea1.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Grande", 8F);
chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.DashDot;
chartArea1.AxisY.ScaleView.MinSizeType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
chartArea1.CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
chartArea1.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
chartArea1.CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;
chartArea1.CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
this.chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
this.chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-4, 0);
this.chart1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.chart1.Name = "chart1";
series1.BorderWidth = 3;
series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Point;
series1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
series1.IsXValueIndexed = true;
series1.LabelBorderWidth = 2;
series1.MarkerColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
series1.Name = "Series1";
series1.XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.UInt32;
series1.YValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.UInt32;
this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);
this.chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1031, 618);
this.chart1.TabIndex = 5;
```

Comment: Can you show us more code and a screenshot of the chart ?

Comment: i'd love to but i cannot upload pics because i'm not allowed to. i may have touched some settings in properties window, but i can't remember them

Comment: Which is the series ChartType ? Point ?

Comment: yes  they are points. i also tried to set to stepline, still, all x distances are same

Comment: I believe you should set the `Interval` property of the X axis to say 1, this should help you get the result as you visualize

Comment: OK, that piece of code works fine on my machine with default settings. You say your problem lies in some properties you changed and you don't rember, but since you can't post anything I doubt we can help you. So, my suggestion is to remove your chart from the form and re-add it to reset properties to their default...

Comment: code posted. (how do i make it look like code rather than meaningless strings. :p)

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

```
 series1.IsXValueIndexed = true;
```

this is the reason that happened.
it should be false.
thanx for everyone's attention.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use empty DataPoints, (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456677.aspx )

Using the IsEmpty property, this would lead to the following code.
( `DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints` should require less code, but I did not test it yet )

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(0,1));
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(1,0){IsEmpty=true});
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(2,0){IsEmpty=true});
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(3,0){IsEmpty=true});
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(4,0){IsEmpty=true});
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(5,0){IsEmpty=true});
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(6,0){IsEmpty=true});
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(7,1));
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(8,1));
```

Comment: it seems that DataManipulator is only used in vs2012. and i can't add that many points due to performance issue.

Comment: @aihenry2980 DataManipulator appeared in .Net 4 ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datamanipulator%28v=vs.100%29.aspx ) I don't see why you could not use it in VS2010 
thx for the answer, IsXValueIndexed seems to be enough with one serie. Empty DataPoints seem better used when using multiple series

Comment: I never tried multiple series before, i'll try this later. Thanx @jbl